# Segmentation fault opening videos in totem

Tags: video, vlc, totem

I just upgraded (not a fresh install) from 21.10 to 22.04 LTS. The upgrade went well, no issues there.

Unfortunately, I just noticed that I now have some issues when playing videos.  In the last hour or so, I have tried a few different videos all with:

- mkv files with H.264 codec
- mp4 files with H.265 codec

without much success.  The default viewer is `totem` which either seems to be returning the following error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when I run it from the command line.  Or in some cases the video plays but the image is all corrupt (see picture at the bottom)). Note that the very same video can produce either results and it is not consistent.

If, however, I open the same files using VLC or in Chrome, there are no apparent issues playing the videos.  I opened a few AVI files (I do not have many), and there were no issues playing those.

I followed the [steps in *Method 1* described here](https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-install-multimedia-codecs-on-ubuntu-linux/) to see if the issue was one of the proper codecs having been removed during the upgrade.  However, it shows that all codecs are already installed and are already at the latest version.

PS: I do not know if this may be related but during the upgrade, I noticed an odd message that said that `openshot` was going to be removed.

[image: Sample video MKV]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem apparently is related to gstreamer1.0-vaapi package.

Removing it solves the issue:

```
sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

Comment: That worked... Thanks.  Do any of you know what the function of gstreamer1.0-vaapi would be?  That is, once I remove it, would I lose any functionality?

Comment: It's used for hardware V(ideo) A(cceleration) by gstreamer. It will use software acceleration instead. If the command solved the issue, please accept it as solution.

Comment: Thank you!!  Too bad I will not be able to use hardware acceleration.  Video will run slower until that API is made available to use w/ 22.04.